# ElasticSearch query is not working with only 2 characters

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, opensearch

I have a field with this mapping definition

```
        identifierNumber: {
          type: "keyword",
          fields: { text: { type: "text" } },
        },
```

the values of this field look something like this `22-001`,`22-002`, etc
I am making the following query to ElasticSearch

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "status": "NEW"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must": [
                {
                    "simple_query_string": {
                        "query": "22 22~",
                        "fields": [
                            "title^3",
                            "identifierNumber^2"
                        ],
                        "lenient": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": []
}
```

this query returns 0 results.
changing the `simple_query_string` `query` to `22001` or `22-001` will return relevant results.
Can someone explain to me why the original query with only 2 characters does not work?

Comment: Did you mean `22*` (a wildcard), not `22~`? The fuzzy search term `22~` means you expect to match tokens which are within a Damerau-Levenshtein distance of 2 from `22` (as noted [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/9_4_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Fuzzy_Searches)). I don't think terms such as `22-001` will be found, because of this. There are more than 2 steps needed to transform `22` to `22-001`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need add the fields "identifierNumber.text" in simple_query_string clausule.

```
"simple_query_string": {
                        "query": "22 22~",
                        "fields": [
                            "title^3",
                            "identifierNumber.text"
                        ],
                        "lenient": true
                    }
```